# Flask+Nginx，but file download error（file size: 0kb)？

Tags: javascript, nginx, flask

Flask + Nginx

I use `window.open('/Download/test.xls')` in js code,I would like to download the file test.xls

and My code like this:

```
@app.route('/Download/<filename>')
def download(filename):
response = make_response()

response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
response.headers['Content-Description'] = 'File Transfer'
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename

return response
```

and nginx.conf like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  tongji.yunzx.com;

server_name_in_redirect off;

proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

location / {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
    }

location /Download/(.*) {
internal;
root /root/HostMonitor/;
    }
}
```

The file test.xls dowload from the web size is 0kb,and can not open it.Why?

I use tool like xftp to check the test.xls in the server is OK,not broken.but download by chrome is broken.

Tell me why, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you make an response object and attach some headers, but do nothing with the attachment files, so you get a empty file.

In flask, there is a function called [`send_from_directory`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#flask.send_from_directory):

> Send a file from a given directory with send_file(). This is a secure way to quickly expose static files from an upload folder or something similar.

so you can try：

```
@app.route('/Download/<path:filename>')
def download(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename, as_attachment=True)
```